# JMeter Constant Throughput Timer doesn't pause until all threads have started

Tags: jmeter

I am using a Constant Throughput Timer with "Calculate throughput based on: all active threads in current thread group" selected. When I specify 50 threads on the Thread Group and a throughput of 1 sample per minute, I see 50 samples go through immediately and then 1 sample per minute after that. It seems that the Constant Throughput Timer is not being applied to the first sample for each thread.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Here is my test setup.

[image: Constant Throughput Timer setup]

Here are the results of letting it run for a few seconds.

[image]

I expect it to only run one time when it starts, since the throughput is 1.0. After it has launched every thread, it only runs once per minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a workaround. Since the problem is with the first pass through the test plan, I just used a counter and created an "If" controller to identify and skip the first pass through. Not the prettiest answer but it works around the bug.

Counter:
[image]

"If" Controller:
[image]

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting this bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51480

There is a old incomplete patch for it that you may want to try.

You may want to try this plugin:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/

Comment: Thanks for the link! Interesting and relevant, but I must use the stock version of JMeter. Is there a workaround?